# How to use 'marvosim' package in windows8?

Tags: texmaker, windows

I am using Latex with tex editor 'Texmaker' in windows8. But whenever I compile .tex file it shows an error **use package *marvosim/marvosim.sty* not found**. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to install the `marvosym` package in your TeX distribution. See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution).

Comment: and stop calling `marvosym` “`marvosim`”...

Answer (score 2):

Install `marvosym` in your TeX distribution (see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution))

Then add

```
\usepackage{marvosym}
```

to your document preamble. Note the spelling.